# How to display html month tag input already saved in sql in format Month, year?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, date

I have used html input month tag to take a calender entry as was required by client, it was saved as text in sqldatabase table, its in format 2019-03 where as I need it in March-2019 format..

I have used date_format(), date(), strtotime() but its of no use because the input tag is not completely in date format ... and i searched stackoverflow for answers too but could not find any.

When taking input from user

```
<input name= 'apmtr' type= 'month' id='datePicker' value='<?php set_value('apmtr');?>' class='form-control required'>
```

when displaying it to user

```
<?php echo $dsr[0]['apmtr'];?>
```

I need it in March-2019 when taking value from database only using php.

Comment: `strtotime` eats that format perfectly fine, and `date` allows you to format the resulting timestamp however you like …

Comment: If you tried things that didn't work, you should include your attempts in your question along with the results so that we can help point out where you went wrong.

Comment: Thank you 04FS, i knew I need to do something like this, but it was not coming to me .. thanks alot ..

Comment: Patrick, Thank you for your reply mate, I was basically converting $dsr[0]['apmtr'] to date first and then was converting it by strtotime .. still thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is could give you the desired output.

```
<?php 
print date('F-Y', strtotime($string)); // $string would be database column name
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could this directly in mysql  using

```
 select  date_format(str_to_date('2019-03', '%Y-%m'), '%M-%Y')

 select  date_format(str_to_date(your_col_string, '%Y-%m'), '%M-%Y') apmtr
 from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do like this,

```
echo date("F-Y", strtotime("2019-03"));
```

You will get all the formats you are looking for from this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

**Output**

```
March-2019
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4c90fc6034d0ebcfafb5c63b6132f6e47f0bd27)

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
echo date('F-Y', strtotime($dsr[0]['apmtr']));
```